# Data transfer from on prem to azure synapse database with out using ADF

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

Can we move data from onprem sql server to azure synapse with out using a azure data factory?

My main intention behind this is not to have intermediate storage of data in blob or storage container. the bulk insert works in ADF but do we have any other option here.

Answer (score 0):

In case if this is a 1 time activity, you can use database migration assistant tool.
Else you can also leverage ssis to transfer data between on prem sql and synapse.

Comment: thansk for the repsonse, but its not a one time activity and its an incremental load

Comment: Then SSIS can be an option. But you can also prefer to use ADF as there are 3 modes in copy activity to synapse out of which 1 doesn't need blob